# Calling Google Plus Sign In inside of NSObject class rather than ViewController in IOS

Tags: react-native, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I am trying to define methods for user login in my IOS app with Google+. I would like to do this in separate utility class rather than view controller (because I will expose these components to native react.js later).

My class header will look like following:

```
@interface LoginUtility : NSObject<GPPSignInDelegate>
+ (void)googleLogin
```

However, "GPPSignInDelegate" does not work inside NSObject class. After I implement like that, I start getting linker error like:

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMMotionManager", referenced from: objc-class-ref in GooglePlus(GPPSpamSignal.o)".

- Note: I added all dependency libraries.

When I put the same code in ViewController, it just works fine. I also tried same logic with Facebook login and it worked perfectly.

Why is Google enforcing sign in method to be called inside ViewController?
Are there any ways to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`CMMotionManager` is part of the `CoreMotion` framework.  You obviously haven't linked that in correctly.

Comment: CoreMotion.framework is already part of "Link Binary with Libraries" section. I also think it should have failed when I make the same call in ViewController (if something is not linked properly). But, I only get this error when I make call from NsObject class.